# Yocto error adding layer meta-openembedded/meta-python

Tags: yocto, yocto-layer

cloned the repository:

https://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/?h=nanbield

Then tried to add the layer meta-openembedded/meta-python by using the command:

bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-openembedded/meta-python/

but this is the error:

```
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
ERROR: Layer 'meta-python' depends on layer 'openembedded-layer', but this layer is not enabled in your configuration
ERROR: Parse failure with the specified layer added, exiting.

Based on the error, tried to add only the layer meta-openembedded before adding layer meta-openembedded/meta-python and this is the error:

NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
Specified layer directory /home/gachaconr/yoctonanbield/poky/meta-openembedded doesn't contain a conf/layer.conf file
```

Can someone please help me providing me directions on how to add the mentioned layer?

Answer (score 0):

Add /poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe layer to your build/conf/layer.conf file

You can use: `bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-openembedded/meta-oe`

Then check using : `bitbake-layers show-layers`